# Magento 2 : Override front-end router

Tags: magento2, overrides, router

I try to **override** a **router**, and I encounter some difficulties.

I try an override in the following way:

In my module2 DI : **namespace2/module2/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="{Namespace1}\{module1}\Controller\Router" type="{Namespace2}\{module2}\Controller\Router" />
</config>
```

In my module2 frontend routes : **namespace2/module2/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="{namespace2}">
            <module name="{namespace2}_{module2}" before="{namespace1}_{module1}" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

In my module2 router : **namespace2/module2/Controller/Router**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace2\Module2\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Router extends \Namespace1\Module1\Controller\Router
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        die('ok');
    }
}
```

But after DI compile, my override not works.

Can you help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't create a rewrite config in di.xml file. It should be config scripts to add your controller router class to router list in Magento. It will work properly. For Example:

- In di.xml file (It should be place in etc/frontend folder or etc/adminhtml folder if the uri is admin)

  ```
  <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
      <arguments>
          <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="router_name" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Module\Controller\Router</item>
                  <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                  <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">50</item>
              </item>
          </argument>
      </arguments>
  </type>
  ```
- Create Router class implements RouterInterface like this one:

  ```
  namespace Namespace\Module\Controller;

  class Router implements RouterInterface
  {
      public function __construct() {

      }

      /**
       * Match application action by request
       *
       * @param RequestInterface $request
       * @return ActionInterface
       */
      public function match(RequestInterface $request)
      {
          // TODO: Implement match() method.
      }
  }
  ```